# UITableView not showing in order SWIFT

Tags: ios, json, swift, uitableview

having some issue with tableview. The JSon content is in the right order but when i update the table thats when the problem starts. This is how i update the table:

```
var cats = [Categories]()

func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    cats.count
}
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cellIdentifier = "CategoryTableViewCell"
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CategoryTableViewCell
        print(cats[indexPath.row].categoryName)
        cell.nameLabel.text = cats[indexPath.row].categoryName
        cell.subNameLabel.text = cats[indexPath.row].appShortDesc
    return cell
}
```

When i print the JSon it shows the correct order just the tableview keeps doing what it feels like.

Comment: Your code looks fine and suggests the tableView would display in the same order as the Array. Why are you sure they are different?

Comment: That looks like how the table is created initially, do you fetch any data after that point and if so how do you reload the table?

Comment: Show us how `cats` is being filled. Remember that in Swift [Arrays are ordered while Dictionaries **are not**](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/CollectionTypes.html). If you're working with Dictionaries you can't have ordered values.